# Is there a way to see the variables declared in a session in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The question is as it is in the 'Title', but for the sake of completeness -

Suppose :

```
>>> a= 23
>>> h ="Liam Neeson"
>>> k ={'a','b','c'}
```

Are three variables. Then I do a whole bunch of other stuff. And I want to see what variables I have initialised so far, is there a way to do it? Something that will return

> > > [a,h,k].

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir : `dir()`

Comment: Oh okay, thanks :) And here I thought I'd Googled enough -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want user defined variables, you could use [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) and strip out the builtins:

```
set(dir()) - set(dir(__builtins__)) - {'__builtins__'}
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> a = 23
>>> h = "Liam Neeson"
>>> k = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
>>> set(dir()) - set(dir(__builtins__)) - {'__builtins__'}
{'a', 'h', 'k'}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, using the [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) function:

> dir([object])
>   Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local scope. With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object.

example:

```
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> a = 1
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'a']
```